# Uniform convergence of $ U_n(x) = \sum_{n=0}^{+ \infty} (-1)^n \ln ( 1 + \frac{x}{1+ nx} ) $.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

> We consider the series of functions:
>
> $$U_n(x) = \sum_{k=0}^{n} (-1)^k \ln \left( 1 + \frac{x}{1+ kx} \right)  ,~ x \geq0.$$
>
> 1. Prove that $U_n$ is convergent.
> 2. Study the uniform convergence of $U_n$.
> 3. Study the normal convergence.
> 4. We consider $U(x) = \sum_{n=0}^{+ \infty} (-1)^n \ln ( 1 + \frac{x}{1+ nx} )$. Prove that $U(x)$ is of class $C^1$.
> 5. Compute $U'(x)$.

---

I have problem with question 2 and 4.

**For question 2**. I do not know how to answer this question since I do not know the value of the sum $U_n (x)$ to compute : $\lim sup |U_n(x) - l| $. How to know if the series have uniform convergence?

**For question 4**. $U(x)$ is of class $C^1$ means it is differentiable and its derivative is continuous. If $ \sum U_n$ converges uniformaly, $U$ will have the same properties, but how can I can prove that $U$ is of $C^1$ without computing $U'(x)$ first? I am confused because in the last question I am asked to compute $U'(x)$. Is there a way to deduce that from uniform convergence?

Answer (score -1):

This is a series with alternating sign terms, so a good idea would be to split it into even and odd terms. For even $n$, say $n=2m$, we have
$$U_{2m-1}(x) = \sum_{k=0}^m \ln \left( 1+ \frac{x}{1+2kx} \right) - \ln \left( 1+ \frac{x}{1+(2k+1)x} \right)$$ which (after some calculations) turns out to be
$$\sum_{k=0}^m \ln \left( 1+ \frac{x^2}{(1+2kx)(1+2(k+1)x)} \right)$$

As $m \to + \infty$ this series is normally convergent, thus $U_{2m-1}(x)$ is uniformly convergent on $\Bbb R$. Now you should study the series $U_{2m}$ and conclude similarly.

Thus $U_n$ is uniformly convergent, although it is not normally convergent (since it is not absolutely convergent).

As for differentiability of $U(x)$, you have to apply [this limit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_convergence#To_differentiability) .

Comment: In the order of the problem, I am asked about the uniform convergence first. 

You have started with the normal convergence. Although, I found that: $\sum \sup |U_n(x)| = \sum \ln (1 + \frac{1}{n}) = + \infty $, which is not normally convergent. 

For your last sentence, I want to know about the continuity of $U'(x)$ not the differentiability. I need to prove that $U(x) \in C^1$

Comment: Indeed what I proved is that the series converges uniformly. After that, you have to study the uniform convergence of $U'_n(x)$ in a similar way: since those are continuous, they will converge to a continuous $U'(x)$.